# cannot resolve method 'get key' in Pair in android?

Tags: java, android

I have a problem using functions in Android Studio, where i use the function in Pair library,here's a snippet of my code

```
import android.util.Pair;
Penyakit penyakit = (Penyakit) p.getKey();
```

i need a solution, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is not a `#geyKey` in `android.util.Pair` . You need use property of `pair` which are `first` and `second`. Here `p.first` will be key and `p.second` will be value

```
        Penyakit penyakit = (Penyakit) p.first;
```

Comment: is it the same as getKey in terms of function ?? because this code I use in "netbeans"